# How to lock Map and fix data race

Tags: go, mutex

I'm trying to solve WARNING: DATA RACE
here is the code:

```
package models

import (
  "sync"
  "time"
)
type Stats struct {
    sync.Mutex
    request map[int64]int
}

func (s *Stats) PutRequest() {
  s.Lock()
  s.request[time.Now().Unix()]++
  s.Unlock()
}
func (s *Stats) GetRequests() map[int64]int {
    s.Lock()
    m := s.request
    s.Unlock()
    return m
 }
var Requests = Stats{
    sync.Mutex{},
    make(map[int64]int),
}
```

If i change Stats field request into integer then everithing works fine but not with map. How to correctly lock map in Go?

Comment: The lock doesn't do any good if you return the map you're trying to protect from the `GetRequests` method

Comment: It's not accessing the map itself that needs synchronization, but accessing the map *elements*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  sync.RWMutex

```
func (s *Stats) PutRequest(ut int64) {
  s.Lock()
  defer s.Unlock()
  s.request[ut]++
}
```

---

```
func (s *Stats)  GetRequests() map[int64]int {
    s.RLock()
    defer s.RUnlock()
    m := make(map[int64]int, len(s.request))
    for k, v := range s.request {
        m[k] = v
    }
    return m
}
```

The following channel example can be interesting in this case. [go by example - stateful goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/stateful-goroutines)

Anyway you need to copy the map before returning it.

Comment: Is the RWMutex really needed. I'd say at it's core, you are suggesting to make a copy of `s`,which could be protected by a simple mutex as well.

Comment: With "simple mutex" one read will block a second concurrent read.  
With RWMutex several reads can read simultaneously.
`A RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer`
https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex

Comment: I perfectly understand the RWMutex, I only fail to see the need to add complexity - however minor it may be - since at the core of the question the problem was that instead of returning a copy of the map a reference to the map was returned.

Comment: Thanks, map copy helped

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I see your point. Its a small snippet and very idiomatic so I decided to add it.

Answer (score 1):

`GetRequests` returns the reference to the map, so if other code calls the function and do r/w on the returning map without acquiring the lock, then data race is introduced